# How to add section numbering when using Sphinx with rst2pdf

Tags: python-sphinx, rst2pdf

I am unable to turn on automatic section numbering using Sphinx together with rst2pdf.

The `sectnum` directive does not work. Is it possible to achieve this result somehow?

Comment: I use rst2pdf **0.16** and Sphinx **1.1.3** (`make latexpdf`), and both give me automatic section numbering. What does *together* mean?

Comment: @Tshepang I use rst2pdf as an output generator for Sphinx.

Answer (score 3):

As seen in the [The Rst2pdf Handbook](https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf/blob/dev/doc/manual.txt), you can do:

```
.. section-numbering::
```

Comment: Are there any options to this directive?

Comment: This only works with a single document sphinx-doc, no nested toctree stuff is supported